# Javascript - Get the content of a string from inside a parenthesis

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string which I get back from an ajax request. The string is in this format:

```
  POINT(417135.05230943 4187636.37572952)
```

What I want is to get the content in the parenthesis to use it to make a marker (latitude, longitude).

Right now I do this:

```
response = response.replace("POINT(",'');
response = response.replace(")",'');
response = response.replace(" ",',');
//alert(response);
var latlotArr = response.split(',');
```

Which I don't like at all. Is there another way to do it? I suppose is not possible to convert this to JSon. What alternatives do I have?

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/hQ0zR3/1 I'm not a regex master, but this regex is just enough if you want to use them, else you can split, splice and join .

Comment: @briosheje you should add your answer (with a minimal explanation and we upvote you for sure

Comment: The regex link above is a good answer, however you might want to change it to something like `/\(([0-9 .]*)\)/` just to filter out any invalid responses (i.e. error messing inside the brackets) by only accepting numbers, '.' and ' ' values.

Comment: @InvernoMuto: I like to try to answer where I perfectly know what I am after... I'm not a regex master, therefore I'm pretty sure that many other users will provide some way more complete answers, that's why I've commented :)

Comment: @briosheje la prossima volta non ti dico niente :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bunch of ways to do it.

One way is a basic regular expression to match the two groups of numbers separated by a space.

```
var str = "POINT(417135.05230943 4187636.37572952)";
var points = str.match(/(\d+.\d+)\s(\d+.\d+)/);
console.log(points[1], points[2]);
```

You can get more specific if you want, up to you.